# How to use setCurrentTransformationMatrix in jsPDF

Tags: jspdf

I'm working with TypeScript, Node.js, and jsPDF, and I've encountered an issue with the setCurrentTransformationMatrix method in jsPDF. My intention was to draw a circle with a center at (100,100) and a radius of 100. However, the output PDF does not reflect this. Below is the code I'm using:

```js
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

const doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'mm' });
doc.setCurrentTransformationMatrix(doc.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 100));
doc.circle(0, 0, 100);
doc.save('output/circle.pdf');
```

I expected this code to produce a PDF with a circle centered at (100,100), but the actual result was different. (I've attached an image of the output for reference.)

Can someone help me understand what's going wrong here? Am I misunderstanding how setCurrentTransformationMatrix works, or is there an issue with my code?

[screenshot of circle.pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rrXE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems one is that units are relative to an image origin rather than a PDF origin so PDF constructs often need Y reversing so down is -Y

The other is related to scaling so you have a hybrid scalar based on mm and inches.

To get what you seem to desire ? with embellishments used while testing.

[image]

I propose based on demo at https://raw.githack.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/index.html

```
/* global jsPDF */
var doc = new jsPDF({ unit: 'mm' });

doc.setDrawColor(0, 0, 255);
doc.setLineWidth(1);
doc.setCurrentTransformationMatrix(doc.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 283.464566929134, -283.464566929134));
doc.circle(0, 0, 99);

doc.setCurrentTransformationMatrix(doc.Matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -283.464566929134, 283.464566929134));
doc.setLineWidth(0.001);
doc.setFillColor(255, 0, 0);
doc.circle(100, 100, 100, "FD");
doc.line(0,0,100,100)
```

the question was raised why the 100 is translated as a required `283.4645669291339` and the reason is that is 100 units x 72pt/25.4mm i.e. 7200/25.4 where 72 is the PDF default points per inch and 25.4 is the mm per inch.

Comment: Thank You for Your Helpful Response. Following your advice, I'm delighted to report that everything worked perfectly!


Also, I have a quick follow-up question. Could you please clarify the meaning of the number 283.464566929134 in the code you provided?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! Really appreciate you breaking it down for me. Now it makes perfect sense.